# php-node Node Express cannot find module

Tags: php, node.js, express, php-node

The error is:

```
Cannot find module 'php'

Error: Cannot find module 'php'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at new View (F:\Users\MichaelJacksonIsDead\publisherServer\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:50:49)
    at EventEmitter.app.render (F:\Users\MichaelJacksonIsDead\publisherServer\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:545:12)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (F:\Users\MichaelJacksonIsDead\publisherServer\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:938:7)
    at F:\Users\MichaelJacksonIsDead\publisherServer\routes\index.js:12:6
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (F:\Users\MichaelJacksonIsDead\publisherServer\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
    at next (F:\Users\MichaelJacksonIsDead\publisherServer\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:110:13)
```

The Route for this page to render as php is as follows:

```
router.get('/index.php', function(req, res, next) {
    var render = require('php-node')({bin:"F:\\xampp\php\\php.exe"});
    res.render('index.php');
});
```

I have run a npm install -g, npm install node-php -g at both project level and level above with no success:

```
F:\Users\MichaelJacksonIsDead\publisherServer>npm install -g
publisherServer@0.0.0 F:\Users\MichaelJacksonIsDead\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mod
ules\publisherServer
├── php-node@0.0.2
├── debug@2.2.0 (ms@0.7.1)
├── serve-favicon@2.2.1 (ms@0.7.1, fresh@0.2.4, parseurl@1.3.0, etag@1.6.0)
├── cookie-parser@1.3.5 (cookie@0.1.3, cookie-signature@1.0.6)
├── morgan@1.5.3 (basic-auth@1.0.1, depd@1.0.1, on-finished@2.2.1)
├── body-parser@1.12.4 (bytes@1.0.0, content-type@1.0.1, depd@1.0.1, raw-body@2.
0.2, on-finished@2.2.1, qs@2.4.2, iconv-lite@0.4.8, type-is@1.6.2)
├── express@4.12.4 (merge-descriptors@1.0.0, utils-merge@1.0.0, methods@1.1.1, f
resh@0.2.4, cookie@0.1.2, escape-html@1.0.1, cookie-signature@1.0.6, range-parse
r@1.0.2, content-type@1.0.1, parseurl@1.3.0, finalhandler@0.3.6, vary@1.0.0, ser
ve-static@1.9.3, content-disposition@0.5.0, path-to-regexp@0.1.3, depd@1.0.1, on
-finished@2.2.1, qs@2.4.2, etag@1.6.0, proxy-addr@1.0.8, send@0.12.3, type-is@1.
6.2, accepts@1.2.7)
├── hjs@0.0.6 (hogan.js@3.0.2)
└── less-middleware@1.0.4 (mkdirp@0.3.5, node.extend@1.0.10, less@1.7.5)

F:\Users\MichaelJacksonIsDead\publisherServer>npm start

> publisherServer@0.0.0 start F:\Users\MichaelJacksonIsDead\publisherServer
> node ./bin/www

GET /index.php 500 41.145 ms - 954
```

Does anyone have any expirence with this issue? As far as I can tell I have correctly installed it... also to make sure I added the package to my json file as follows:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.12.4",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.12.4",
    "hjs": "~0.0.6",
    "less-middleware": "1.0.x",
    "morgan": "~1.5.3",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.2.1",
    "php-node": "0.0.2"
  }
```

Lastly I did not have enough rep to open a tag php-node for the project @ https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-node, not a issue but would of been nice to have a more speficic tag :)

Comment: It doesn't look like you followed the [instructions](https://github.com/digplan/php-node), but instead you required the middleware inside the route ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer, thank you @mscdex and @adeneo

I replaced the default:

```
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hjs');
```

with

```
// use PHP as view engine in Express
var phpnode = require('php-node')({bin:"F:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe"});
app.engine('php', phpnode);
app.set('view engine', 'php');
```

under routes:

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index.hjs', { title: 'Express' });
});


router.get('/index.php', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index.php');
});
```

The app still supports php and index.hjs pages.

Answer (score 2):

You should **only** use `-g` when you're installing a module from npm that contains a command line utility (e.g. `express-generator` is an example of this). However in almost all cases you should just simply do `npm install <module name>` which will install the module locally and allow you to `require()` it.

So do `npm install` in your project's root directory and `require()` should be able to find `php-node`.

Answer (score 0):

only if the plugin are use you are not 100% happy of it there is a simple method(this is only a prototype so if you are node.js expert you may improve it) to build FROM ONLY ONE SERVER APPS NODE.JS  - PHP (and theoretical you have yet sqlite3 and after installing a mariadb or mysql server you can use them as well) :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68422021/5781320