# Setting up node-php to deliver php files to client using express?

Tags: node.js, express

Node-php is an npm package: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-php#nodephp---run-wordpress-and-other-php-scripts-with-node

My problem: Up until now I only needed static html files for my webpage, which were delivered okay.

However, now I want to deliver a php file as well. If i simply try to send it like a static file a popup to save the file appears instead of displaying it. So i set up node-php which claims to be able to deliver php files correctly as well. But, it's not working.

[How the webpage looks with the below code, going to either the html page or the php page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz8pG.jpg)

Either help to make node-php work, or another method to fix this are appreciated.

```
var express = require('express');
var php = require("node-php"); //Required by node-php
var path = require("path"); //Required by node-php
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use("/", php.cgi("/usr/bin/php")); //Required by node-php

//LISTEN
app.set('port', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080);
app.set('ip', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1');

http.listen(app.get('port'), app.get('ip'), function () {
console.log('LISTENING!');
});

app.use(express.static('public'));

//SEND FILES
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/phpfile', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/phpfile.php');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument passed to `php.cgi()` is supposed to be your PHP root directory (where your PHP files are located), not the path to a PHP binary.

Comment: Ah! Will test and report back.

Comment: I changed the line to "/var/lib/openshift/5716b3a77628e152370001d2/app-root/repo", which is the path to the files. However, all i get now when i go to any page is "No input file specified" in plaintext. :/

Answer (score 0):

just in case you need only one server node and need to build around  an node + php app i put here a method https://stackoverflow.com/a/68422021/5781320 that not involve this plugin (node-php) .so basically you can use node server and get post from a specific page(you can improve the node.js part , `cause it`s only a prototype)